# Is there a WPF check box control toggle event?

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, toggle

Considering WPF controls, how do I know if a check box's value has changed (toggled)?

I know there are the common `Checked`, `Unchecked`, `Clicked` events, but how about an event for when the value changes, regardless of how it was changed?

I looked through the events and I didn't find anything, but maybe I'm missing the obvious (as it has happened many times in the past).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just bind `IsChecked` Dependency Property to a boolean. On that binded property setter you can manipulate what you want (independently if it's setting it to true or false). That works just as expected.

On your view:

```
  <Grid>
    <CheckBox ... IsChecked="{Binding ShowPending}"/>
  </Grid>
```

On your DataContext ViewModel or CodeBehind.

```
  private bool showPending = false;

  public bool ShowPending
  {
      get { return this.showPending; }
      set 
      { 
         //Here you mimic your Toggled event calling what you want!
         this.showPending = value; 
      }
  }
```

Comment: I have never used binding, and as I am trying your suggestion now, I am getting a bit confused. Could you give me a quick example please?

Comment: Sorry if I am a pain, but can this be done entirely in C#? I would like to stay away from XAML editing as much as possible.

Comment: @IneedHelp As you see everything is done within C#. The view part can be replaced with plain C# (declaring the Checkbox and setting the binding on IsChecked).

Comment: @RandolfR-F Does your answer toggle the IsChecked property when changed from code-behind or WPF? I thought without the INotifyPropertyChanged inheritance it was only one-way from source to target when source changes? I think tylergarland's will handle change from both and notify.

Answer (score 6):

I know this already has an accepted answer, but binding is a bit overkill on this.

Just write one event handler and wire it to both the Checked and Unchecked events then check the IsChecked property inside your event handler.

Comment: actually I think DataBinding is less of an overkill than a new event handler. Additionally you can check or uncheck the checkbox without having the object.

Comment: they're both acceptable solutions. I prefer mine because I'd rather not use multiple bindings on the control when its time to attach it to an actual data object. There's also maintenance to think of and I feel its clearer where the events are handled if its on actual event handlers rather than hidden in a binding.

Answer (score 1):

Going off Randolf's answer, just create a class representing your window. 
In the new class, create a property called BlahIsChecked. Implement the INotifyPropertChangedEvent in the class and in the setter of the the new property, fire the event with the property name.

```
class Blah : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Used for triggering the event
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // Called when the property changes
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        // Retrieve handler
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        // Check to make sure handler is not null
        if(handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private bool _blahIsChecked;
    public bool BlahIsChecked
    {
        get {
            return _blahIsChecked;
        }
        set {
            _blahIsChecked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("BlahIsChecked);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, go to your wpf class and say this.DataContext = new MainModel(); You can do this in WPF or c#.

Now in your checkbox xaml do the following

```
<checkbox Checked="{Binding BlahIsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

I did this from memory but should get you started. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is probably the `IsChecked` property. But if you require an event, you can look at creating a [`DependencyPropertyDescriptor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dependencypropertydescriptor.aspx) and registering a handler with the [`AddValueChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dependencypropertydescriptor.addvaluechanged.aspx) method.

I think this is about as close as you'll get to an evented notification that the check box's value has changed. Creating the descriptor and adding the handler looks something like this:

```
var dpd = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(CheckBox.IsChecked, typeof(CheckBox));
dpd.AddValueChanged(...);
```